# RichTextBox Globalization

Tags: .net, richtextbox, globalization

I am making a webservice that will need to create/manipulate rich text used by the client in a Windows/DotNet RichTextBox.
The users of the service will be from all around the world.

The service accepts a string supplied by the client from RichTextBox.Rtf, does some manipulation and returns a string to the client which is put back into the Rtf field of the textbox.

Works fine but I have some concerns about globalization, for instance..

An empty RichTextBox on my dev machine has the Rtf as:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1044{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs17\par
}
```

When a new record is created, the service needs to provide some default formatted text.
I am assuming that someone that has a different language on their OS install will have different font, ansicodepage and deflang for the default empty RichTextBox.
So I found I can supply the following string for a new record without getting a format exception...

```
{\rtf1\ansi\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs17 MyTextGoesHere\par}
```

After setting RichTextBox.Rtf to the above, I then inspect the Rtf and find it has reinserted the font and deflang as below...

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang1044\f0\fs17 MyTextGoesHere\par}
```

Questions:

1> Should I worry about this or must I keep stripping it out at my service?

2> Is it safe to strip it out? Will the clients still be able to use charachters from their language in the text?

3> Will it be cross language compatible? If I view the richtext using an OS/Language different than another user, will it look normal?

Any recomendations or pointers?

Comment: It is *very* unclear why you worry about fonts.  This is just markup that affects the *formatting* of the text, not the *meaning* of the text.  Formatting is meant for human eyes, not machines.  Surely your service only cares about the information that's encoded in the text and not what it looks like?  Even if you transmit RTF, you'd still use the Text property on the receiving end to find out what it means.  Or you'd just not bother and transmit the Text instead.

Comment: I am mostly worried that a client viewing text created by another user with a different language will get some kind of format exception when they try to view it. Secondary worry is that it will look like complete garbage and think something is wrong with my Service/Application.

Comment: There won't be any format exceptions, everybody uses the same RTB and RTF.  It will just look like Chinese to him.

Comment: Ok, thats acceptable. But what about my stripped down RTF for a new record. Do you think that will cause any problems for any OS/Language combinations? It seems the OS puts in its needed Font/Language info, but it doesnt put an ansicodepage in there. Do you think ALL OS/Languages can accept it as a start and still allow the local user to see things properly on their OS?

Comment: I think I am going to ask the user for his desired Rtf (supplied by his local OS RichTextBox) to use as when creating the new record. Then just assume it is empty and tack on my stuff at the end.

Comment: What is proper thing to do when someone does not submit an "answer" but does help in comments? 
Create own answer and accept it? Or just leave the question open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I am going to ask the user for his desired Rtf (supplied by his local OS RichTextBox) to use as when creating the new record. Then just assume it is empty and tack on my stuff at the end.